# javascript onmousemove get relative coordinates

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function aim() {
    var mousex = ?
}

<div class="gameArea" onmousemove="aim();"> </div>
```

I can't find how to get the mouse coordinates for an onmousemove event in javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var guide = null;

function aim(event) {
    if(window.event)
        event = window.event; //grrr IE
    var mousex = event.clientX - guide.offsetLeft;
    alert('mouse x' + mousex)
}
function init() {
    guide = document.getElementById("guide")
    guide.onmousemove = aim;
}

<body onload="init();">
```

This appears to work on both browsers. I cant do onmousemove="aim();" in html because it doesn't pass the mousemove event object.

Comment: "I cant do onmousemove="aim();" in html because it doesn't pass the mousemove event object." You can do `arguments[0]`

Answer (score 2):

The above example using **guide.offsetLeft** only works if the enclosing element is at (0,0). If not, you can use **guide.getBoundingClientRect().left** (and similar for vertical coord)

Answer (score -1):

Take a lot at the following script. I believe it should be exactly what you're looking for.

[Capture Mouse Position](http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html)