# Website scrolls bby following mouse

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Body scroll with mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913229/body-scroll-with-mouse-position)

I am currently working on a website that revolves around the idea of a cartoon room, and the user clicks on different objects in the room to bring up information. However, I have made the room a specific amount of pixels and sometimes it is too big for a certain resolution, thereby causing scroll bars. I was wondering if there is some javascript/jquery that could follow the mouse cursor so that as the user moves around the room, the whole room moves around with them, and the scroll bars can be hidden.
Any ideas what could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. The question is if you should.

You'll need the css:

```
body, html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you listen for the mousemove event. Example: [javascript onmousemove get relative coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657457/javascript-onmousemove-get-relative-coordinates)

Then adjust document.body.scrollTop and document.body.scrollLeft accordingly.

Here is a jQuery example: [Body scroll with mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913229/body-scroll-with-mouse-position)

Another example: [proper use of onmousemove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439420/proper-use-of-onmousemove)